# How to consume a SOAP API using Python. Soap API 1.2 using WCF service

Tags: python, api, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have been working on a project that uses SOAP API. I was provided with two urls

1. (able to consume) and request xml looks like this it uses **LookupUser_Request**.

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:stor="http://www.centershift.com/STORE40/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <stor:GetSiteDetails>
         <!--LookupUser_Request-->
         <stor:LookupUser_Request>
            <stor:Username>?</stor:Username>
            <stor:Password>?</stor:Password>
            <stor:Channel>?</stor:Channel>
         </stor:LookupUser_Request>
         <stor:Request>
            <stor:SiteID>
               <stor:long>?</stor:long>
            </stor:SiteID>
         </stor:Request>
      </stor:GetSiteDetails>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

2. [Link-2 wsdl](https://slc.centershift.com/store40/StoreService.svc?wsdl) But for this one there is no LookupUser_Request and the SOAPUI generated xml looks like. For service **GetSiteUnitDataStatus**

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:stor="http://www.centershift.com/STORE40/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <stor:GetSiteUnitDataStatus>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <stor:Request>
            <stor:SiteID>?</stor:SiteID>
         </stor:Request>
      </stor:GetSiteUnitDataStatus>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

After looking in 1 page docs [docs link](https://centershiftdevx.com/2015/01/22/sws2-api-documentation/). I found out it uses WCF for service and some kind of token authentication.The service I am trying to consume is **GetSiteUnitDataStatus**

There is also an example code provided for a service **GetSiteUnitDataStatus**.
[Link](https://centershiftdevx.com/2017/04/06/sws2-getsiteunitdatastatus-method/)

```cpp
//Example
//We’ll assume you’ve got a web reference, let’s name it Store, in your Visual Studio project. At this point we need to reference our objects. We’ll need the standard service object, a GetSiteUnitDataStatus_Request request object. We can define and create those like this:

// Create a request and response objects
StoreServiceClient client = new StoreServiceClient();
GetSiteUnitDataStatus_Request request = new GetSiteUnitDataStatus_Request();
As with every method we need to pass in credentials. We also set up the parameters for our request.

client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = true;

request.SiteID = 123456;
//Finally we can call the method and pass across the login object and the request object to retrieve the data. It’s a good idea to do this in a Try Catch block.

try
{
    // Call the method that will load the response object
    UnitTypeStatus[] resp;
    resp = client.GetSiteUnitDataStatus(request);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
//Note that if something goes wrong the service will respond with an exception. You’ll want to take a look at that message returned in that exception so it can be debugged.
```

There are not much tutorials or blogs regarding the SOAP API using WCF.

**I will highly appreciate any help that puts me in the right path.**

my code:

```py
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from zeep import Client
from zeep.helpers import serialize_object
import base64 
# SOAP request URL

USERNAME='**********'
PASSWORD='**********'
ORG_ID = 999999
SITE_ID = 9999999999999999

WSDL_URL = "https://slc.centershift.com/store40/StoreService.svc?wsdl"
# Create a Zeep client
client = Client(wsdl=WSDL_URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, Python has three libraries for calling SOAP services: **suds**, **suds-jurko**, and **zeep**.

SUDS is a Python 2 library, and Python 3 installation has a high probability of reporting errors

**suds-jurko** is a new library for solving suds errors.

So here I first suggest you try to see if using the suds library can solve the problem.

For many use cases, the SOAP specification is very bad and unclear. This results in many (older) SOAP servers not implementing the specifications correctly (or implementing them in ways **Zeep** didn't expect).

So I think this document can help you.
[Error Report](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/reporting_bugs.html#reporting-bugs)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
So to check , I first used the SoapUI it creates the request xml and after putting right parameters in the request I am getting 
"<s:Text xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</s:Text>
"

Comment: Make it clear in the documentation you give that ‘they are a Microsoft shop and do not have any users who can assist with setting up SWS2 for the API. However, in the past we have had third parties create a .NET passthrough app and use PHP to access it. This would be your only option at this time to use PHP with SWS2’. So I think you should need to write an application in .net for Python to access.